# Python simple nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, pygame, nested-loops

I am trying a simple nested for loop in python to scan a threshold-ed image to detect the white pixels and store their location. The problem is that although the array it is reading from is only 160*120 (19200) it still takes about 6s to execute, my code is as follows and any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated:

```
im = Image.open('PYGAMEPIC')

r, g, b = np.array(im).T
x = np.zeros_like(b)

height = len(x[0])
width = len(x)

x[r > 120] = 255                                        
x[g > 100] = 0                                      
x[b > 100] = 0              

row_array = np.zeros(shape = (19200,1))
col_array = np.zeros(shape = (19200,1))

z = 0
for i in range (0,width-1):
    for j in range (0,height-1):
        if x[i][j] == 255:
            z = z+1
            row_array[z] = i

            col_array[z] = j
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it shouldn't take 6 seconds.  Trying your code on a 160x120 image takes ~0.2 s for me.

That said, for good `numpy` performance, you generally want to avoid loops.  Sometimes it's simpler to vectorize along all except the smallest axis and loop along that, but when possible you should try to do everything at once.  This usually makes things both faster (pushing the loops down to C) and easier.

Your for loop itself seems a little strange to me-- you seem to have an off-by-one error both in terms of where you're starting storing the results (your first value is placed in `z=1`, not `z=0`) and in terms of how far you're looking (`range(0, x-1)` doesn't include `x-1`, so you're missing the last row/column-- probably you want `range(x)`.)

If all you want is the indices where `r > 120` but neither `g > 100` nor `b > 100`, there are much simpler approaches.  We can create boolean arrays.  For example, first we can make some dummy data:

```
>>> r = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(8,8))
>>> g = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(8,8))
>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(8,8))
```

Then we can find the places where our condition is met:

```
>>> (r > 120) & ~(g > 100) & ~(b > 100)
array([[False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then we can use `np.where` to get the coordinates:

```
>>> r_idx, c_idx = np.where((r > 120) & ~(g > 100) & ~(b > 100))
>>> r_idx
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5])
>>> c_idx
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1])
```

And we can sanity-check these by indexing back into `r`, `g`, and `b`:

```
>>> r[r_idx, c_idx]
array([166, 175, 155, 150, 241, 222])
>>> g[r_idx, c_idx]
array([ 6, 29, 19, 62, 85, 31])
>>> b[r_idx, c_idx]
array([67, 97, 30,  4, 50, 71])
```

Comment: That you for your response, i had forgotten to mention that i am using the Raspberry Pi to implement this. Implementing the boolean arrays by your method is alot easier but it still doesnt resolve the problem where i have to identify the the white pixels in this image and store their location. i still need a way of scanning the image where i can recognise the white pixels and store them without it taking 6 or so seconds to implement

Comment: I don't understand.  The above code uses your rule for what constitutes a white pixel -- `(r > 120) & ~(g > 100) & ~(b > 100))` -- and gives the indices where the white pixels are, as `r_idx` and `c_idx` are your `row_array` and `col_array` without the wasted space for the zeros.  Anyway, hopefully someone else will be able to help you out!

Comment: Oh wow, sorry my head was burnt out from looking at the computer screen all day! That works great thank you so much! now i can get rid of those evil for loops! and it only takes 0.0117s!! thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to help.  Just to be clear, the only line you really need is `r_idx, c_idx = np.where((r > 120) & ~(g > 100) & ~(b > 100))`, everything else was just for illustration.

Comment: ye i got it no problem! Thats so great i never even thought of that, that has improved my whole program by 1000000%! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

e you're on python 2.x (2.6 or 2.7). In python 2, every time you call `range` you're creating a list with that many elements. (In this case, you're creating 1 list of `width - 1` length, and then `width - 1` lists of `height - 1` length. One way to speed this up is to make one list of each ahead of time and use that list each time.

For example

```
height_indices = range(0, height - 1)
for i in range(0, width - 1):
    for j in height_indices:
        # etc
```

To prevent python having to create either list, you can use `xrange` to return a generator which will save memory and time, e.g.,

```
for i in xrange(0, width - 1):
    for j in xrange(0, height - 1):
        # etc.
```

You should also look into using the `filter` function which takes a function and executes it. It will return a list of items returned by the function but if all you're doing is incrementing a global counter and modifying global arrays, you don't have to return anything or concern yourself with the list returned.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your responce, i have forgotten to mention that i am using the raspberry pi with version 2.7 of python. I have tried your method of making the list ahead of time and this saves about 0.2s but still leaves me with an implementation time of about 5s. would you have any other ideas of checking the image (black with a blob of white pixels) and identifing these while pixels and storing them?